# "Clone" a Virtuozzo VPS

Tags: linux, vps, virtuozzo

We have a rhel running on a VPS, I want to bring it to our network server, a vmware esx. Is it possible?
Any advice would be great, tks!

Answer (score 1):

Certainly ESX can't open or use Virtuozzo containers and as far as I'm aware Virtuozzo can't save in the open .OVF format that ESX can read - you should be able to run the VMWare converter agent inside the Virtuozzo VM and convert it to a native ESX VM however.

Answer (score 0):

vzv2p Virtuozzo utility should be able to do it, see [here](http://download.swsoft.com/virtuozzo/virtuozzo4.0/docs/en/lin/VzLinuxReference/12189.htm) and "man vzv2p"